# How to decide if a Python function call involves network IO operations without reading all the related source codes?

Tags: python, networking

Some of the service clients try to connect the server in the constructors, while others not.

When I'm not sure if constructing a certain client is expensive because of network IO operations, I cache all of them.

What can I do to find out which functions involve network IO?

Comment: The behaviour is not otherwise documented...?

Comment: Read the docs when they exist, and if they don't and you must use a poorly documented tool, experiment and document what you have experimented...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Could you please tell me what tools can I use to conveniently detect whether any network IO happens? I'm not familiar with networking, so the only way I can think of is to read the source code and see if I can find something like `socket`.